# ‘VM_EXECUTABLE’ undeclared

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I just started learning Linux development and for the training purpose I wrote a simple loadable kernel module. When I try to add it by issuing the following command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘VM_EXECUTABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if ((vma->vm_flags & VM_EXECUTABLE) && vma->vm_file)
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Are you missing a header file include? If you search for `VM_EXECUTABLE` in the kernel source tree, do you see it defined somewhere?

Comment: This is what i got:

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/syscall.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/mount.h>

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, edit your question to include relevant information like that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, next time I won't.

Comment: I was able to solve it. The solution is VM_EXEC instead of VM_EXECUTABLE.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
[link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.3;i=VM_EXECUTABLE)

Miss aparently include/linux/mm.h ?

Comment: hi, thanks. I added the following but still the same :

#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/mman.h>